# HQL Min Max, how to

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have two object : "Mother" and "Child".
Mother have many Children,
How can i get from the DB a Mother with only 2 Children (or less), the younger and the older.
Thanks

edit:

The mother i want to get have a lot of children but i only want the younger and the older.

Something like that :

from Mother m left join m.Child c
where (max(c.age) or min(c.age))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this and it works :

```
from M as m    
left join m.C as c
where m.Id = :idM
and
(c.Age = (select min(c.Age) from C c where c.M.Id = :idM)
or
c.Age = (select max(c.Age) from C c where c.M.Id = :idM))
order by c.Age
```

Answer (score 1):

```
FROM Mother m WHERE count(m.Children) <= 2
```